# pip install sanic : command 'gcc' terminated by signal 11

Tags: macos, gcc, pip, python-3.6, sanic

So I am trying to install sanic on my mac os yosemite but for some reason everytime I try to install it, it just returns this error.

```
    building 'ujson' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/python
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/lib
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I./python -I./lib -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c ./python/ujson.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/./python/ujson.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
error: command 'gcc' terminated by signal 11

Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/f8/vtw38lxs63d18dj7sztkyp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-74t39yin/ujson/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/f8/vtw38lxs63d18dj7sztkyp9w0000gn/T/pip-record-0hl9eodf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f8/vtw38lxs63d18dj7sztkyp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-74t39yin/ujson/
```

It also happens when I try to install vibora (another asynchronous web framework) or eventlet for flask websocket

Comment: This is a common error, you need to install gcc and python-dev: `sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev`

Comment: Nevermind I was able to solve the problem by installing Sanic, thank you John for trying to help.